# What is sense type element in @XmlElement annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

What is sens type element in @XmlElement annotation?

sth like this:

```
XmlElement(name = "userId", type = Long.class)
private Long id;
```

It is not used during XML generation.

Answer (score 1):

The `type` property on `@XmlElement` is used in the following scenarios:

1. Most common case is for untyped lists when you have `List` instead of `List<String>` you would use `type=String.class`.
2. When your property type is an interface you use it to specify the impl class.
3. When `@XmlElement` is used with `@XmlElements` to model a choice the `type` property maps the element to a class.
4. Normally an `XmlAdapter` can't be applied to a datatype.  Using type to bump it up to the correspond object type fixes this problem.
5. If you want to force an `xsi:type` attribute to be marshalled you can specify `type=Object.class`.